# GA4 Events show up in Realtime but not in Engagement/Events

Tags: google-bigquery, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I'm sending events with google measurement protocol for Google Analytics 4.
The JSON Body i'm sending looks like:

```
{
   "clientId":"14324532860.16532452526",
   "events":[
      {
         "name":"Monitor_Backend",
         "params":{
            "LicenseSeedStatic":"fefrefervreaihnoigvrioeang",
            "LicenseSeedDynamic":"fgewfreafcaefjnkrgnabfdv",
            "event_action":"Launched Monitor"
         }
      }
   ],
   "userProperties":{
      "anonymous_id":{
         "value":"fefrefervreaihnoigvrioeang"
      }
   }
```

I'm quite new to events and tracking and i don't understand why the events i sent do show up in the Realtime Dashboard but not under Engagement/Event and also not in BigQuery. So what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait up to 24 hours after the event was sent to see it in the reports.